# error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, header-files

I want to write a simple C++ code in visual studio 2012 but always getting a error C1004 in the header file. Could anyone please help me?

My code is given below. I am new in visual studio C++, so this may be very silly error.

**add.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

**add.h**

```
#ifndef ADD_H
#define ADD_H

int add(int a, int b);

#endif
```

**source.cpp**

```
#include "add.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << add(3, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @melpomene: It's in the title of the question.

Comment: That's not the complete message.

Answer (score 17):

The general code looks OK, but add.h will need a carriage return at the end of the file. Here is the Microsoft documentation for that error code:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4exw7xyc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have added a carriage return at the end of the header file and it's working now :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try copying your code to a text editor like Notepad++ and change encoding to ANSI. You may see some strange symbols, for example

```
int main()
{
    // ...
}п»ї
```

To fix the error, remove them and copy the code back.